# Show that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h} = \ln e = 1$ using at least two numerical examples.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Show that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h} = \ln e = 1$$ using at least two numerical examples.

To solve this should I find numbers for $h$ that makes those equations equal to $1$? And how should I go about finding the number? Guess and check?

Comment: I'd simply plug in some very small values of $h$ into $\frac{e^h-1}{h}$ using a calculator.

Comment: so guess and check then?

Comment: I don't see what else they would mean by numerical examples.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a terrible problem as written. It seems you are expected to plug in two small values of $h$ to $\frac {e^h-1}h$ and find the result to be close to $1$.  It will be as long as you don't choose $h$ too small so you get killed by roundoff or errors in your exponential function.  If you choose $h=10^{-6}$ and [have Alpha find](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(exp(10%5E(-6))-1)%2F10%5E(-6)) $\frac {e^h-1}h\approx 1.000000500000166666708333341666668055555753968278769844025$ are you supposed to conclude the limit for small $h$ is exactly $1$?  If I do it in Excel with $h=10^{-15}$ I get $\frac {e^h-1}h=1.110223025
$, not at all close to $1$  None of this proves the limit is $1$

Answer (score 0):

when h is very small, you can do Taylor expansion, $$e^h=1+h+h^2/2!+h^3/3!+h^4/4!+...$$
So, $$\frac{e^h-1}{h}=1+h/2!+h^2/3!+h^3/4!+..$$

give $h=0.01$, $$\frac{e^h-1}{h}\approx 1.005$$
give $h=0.001$,$$\frac{e^h-1}{h}\approx 1.0005$$

Comment: But doesn't a Taylor expansion require one to know how to differentiate $e^x$, which in turn requires one to know the above limit?